# Showing unique values/levels for each character/factor variable at once?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, exploratory-data-analysis

How to show unique values/levels for each character/factor variable at once?

**Data**

```
library(tidyverse)

d = tibble(age = rnorm(10, 50, 3),
           sex = rep(c("male", "female"), 5),
           name = letters[1:10]) %>% 
  mutate(sex = as.factor(sex))

d
```

[image]

**Checking variables one-by-one is time consuming as I work with large datasets**

```
levels(d$sex)
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMJRN.png) "female" "male"

**Expected result should be something like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
d %>% mutate_all(funs(replace(., duplicated(.), NA)))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
     age sex    name 
   <dbl> <fct>  <chr>
 1  54.0 male   a    
 2  50.3 female b    
 3  49.1 NA     c    
 4  47.0 NA     d    
 5  49.6 NA     e    
 6  51.0 NA     f    
 7  54.4 NA     g    
 8  56.9 NA     h    
 9  47.3 NA     i    
10  52.4 NA     j
```

To sort the values and push NA to the last rows

```
d %>% 
  mutate_all(list(~replace(., duplicated(.), NA))) %>% 
  mutate_all(list(~sort(., na.last = TRUE))) %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ !is.na(.))) # To remove rows with all NA's
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do show that it will omit the original row structure, meaning that all unique values are shown on the first top rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  select(!where(is.numeric)) %>%
  split.default(names(.)) %>%
  lapply(unique)
  
$name
name
1:    a
2:    b
3:    c
4:    d
5:    e
6:    f
7:    g
8:    h
9:    i
10:    j

$sex
sex
1:   male
2: female
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the argument maxsum in the function summary to display as many levels as you like for each factor.

```
d = data.frame(age = rnorm(10, 50, 3),
           sex = rep(c("male", "female"), 5),
           name = letters[1:10])
d$sex <- as.factor(d$sex)
d$name <- as.factor(d$name)

summary(d, maxsum = 10000000)
```